# D3 Authorization in angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular5, angular6

I'm trying to get the data from an api and use d3.js to plot the graph. But I'm unable to get the data due to 401 Authorization error. How to pass the token value to the d3 method ?

> **service.ts**

//This service is what i used to get data . I need to use this for plotting the graph also.

```
  rec_source(){

    var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    var options =  {
      headers: headers
  };
  return this.httpClient.get('api/recruit/fetch_recruitment_details',options)
  }
```

> **component.ts**

//what is the changes I have to make here?

```
 d3.json('api/recruit/fetch_recruitment_details/')
  .then(function(data){
    data.forEach(function(d){
      console.log(d);

    })
  })
```

//**error**

[image: console error]

//header error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
you should use Bearer instead of Token in set Authorization like:

```
  var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));
```

Comment: I'm able to get the data from the service I wrote. I just need to know how to use that in the component.ts as I need to pass that token in the d3 method

Comment: you want to get data coming from backend?

Comment: yes the data from the api. Like I'm able to get the data and use it in the other parts of my projects. But while plotting graph they are again asking for authorization. So I need to know how to pass the token in d3 method.

Comment: d3.json('api/recruit/fetch_recruitment_details/')
      .header("header-name", "header-value").then( ......    In header you can pass value of Authorization, etc.

Comment: If you still face problem then I will give another solution of using callback than promise.

Comment: Still not getting it

Comment: d3.json('api/recruit/fetch_recruitment_details/')
  .header("Authorization", "Bearer token_value")
  .get(function(error, data) {
 data.forEach(function(d){
      console.log(d);
  })

Comment: tried both the ways you said, still not getting bro :(

Comment: I just added the picture above. Check it out

Comment: are you using d3-fetch npm package?

Comment: No, I'm just using d3 npm package.

Comment: its easy to use d3-request or d3-fetch than d3